# Optimizing PostgreSQL where clause with OR

Tags: postgresql, performance, union, where, postgresql-performance

I have a query that uses an `or` in the where clause. It is slow. It seems that re-writing the query using a `union` could get the same results much quicker. But I'm in an environment where we generate SQL for different technologies. The `or` clause works well in Oracle, for example. I'd like to consider other options besides `union` that might be less radical if there are any good alternatives.

Here's the minimal setup to make the requirement clear.

```
create table my_table as 
select 
    'EXISTING_RECORDS' as s
  , generate_series(10001,30000) as id
  , chr( ascii('a') + trunc(random() * 26)::int ) || chr( ascii('a') + trunc(random() * 26)::int ) || chr( ascii('a') + trunc(random() * 26)::int ) || chr( ascii('a') + trunc(random() * 26)::int ) || chr( ascii('a') + trunc(random() * 26)::int ) as name
  , chr( ascii('a') + trunc(random() * 26)::int ) || chr( ascii('a') + trunc(random() * 26)::int ) || chr( ascii('a') + trunc(random() * 26)::int ) || chr( ascii('a') + trunc(random() * 26)::int ) || chr( ascii('a') + trunc(random() * 26)::int ) as other_name
;
insert into my_table 
select 
    'NEW_RECORDS' as s
  , generate_series(1001,3000) as id
  , chr( ascii('a') + trunc(random() * 26)::int ) || chr( ascii('a') + trunc(random() * 26)::int ) || chr( ascii('a') + trunc(random() * 26)::int ) || chr( ascii('a') + trunc(random() * 26)::int ) || chr( ascii('a') + trunc(random() * 26)::int ) as name
  , chr( ascii('a') + trunc(random() * 26)::int ) || chr( ascii('a') + trunc(random() * 26)::int ) || chr( ascii('a') + trunc(random() * 26)::int ) || chr( ascii('a') + trunc(random() * 26)::int ) || chr( ascii('a') + trunc(random() * 26)::int ) as other_name
;
```

That create and insert gives us 20k EXISTING_RECORDS and 2k NEW_RECORDS. The name fields are 5 random characters, so we'll end up with a handful of matches when matching based on the following query.

```
select t1.s, t1.id, t1.name, t1.other_name, t2.name, t2.other_name, t2.s, t2.id
from
    my_table t1
  , my_table t2
where
  t1.s = 'NEW_RECORDS'
  and ( 
    t1.name = t2.other_name 
    or 
    t2.name = t1.other_name
  )
;
```

If I reduce the `where` clause to just `t1.name = t2.other_name` or the reverse, then it executes in about **7 ms** in my environment. But with the `or` as shown it takes over **11500 ms**.

I posted the [explain plan](https://explain.depesz.com/s/G20) in case that's helpful.

Is there any reasonable pattern I should consider in order to get a good execution plan besides converting this to two separate queries that I union together? For example: I'm happy to add indexes. But as far as I can tell, that doesn't provide any benefit.

Comment: Creating two indexes: `create index on my_table (name);
create index on my_table (other_name);` on my Postgres 11 installation, changed [this plan](https://explain.depesz.com/s/mHgZ) (8 seconds) to [this plan](https://explain.depesz.com/s/5pEr) (45ms)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think you should post this as an answer, as he did invite new indexes.  It would be nice if it were faster with no added indexes, but the index is better than nothing

Comment: Holy cow. With the problem as stated, the indexes are as effective as @a_horse_with_no_name suggests. For me it reduces from 11,500ms to 19ms. I'm sure I tried this before. (Didn't I??)  I'll go confirm the effectiveness of this change in my full dev environment.

Comment: For what it is worth, there was a proposal to execute some OR as if they were UNIONs, https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/740.1535047846@sss.pgh.pa.us, but it never made it into the released code, and I just tested it and it does not solve your particular problem anyway.  I'm not sure why it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you. I saw similar posts. That's what gave me confidence that rewriting the query as unions would likely work. But in my case at least, adding indexes is far easier. It's surprising to me that this example isn't solved by the proposed update.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
create index on my_table (name); 
create index on my_table (other_name);
```

Credit: @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: I am befuddled that I didn't find this myself. I'm *sure* I tested [multiple] variations of adding indexes, and I don't know how I missed the obvious one. But I'm so happy that I'm giggling, and I'm grateful for the additional eyes on the problem to find this simple workaround.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to rewrite the query if you want it to perform well in PostgreSQL.